# Why am I getting a circular import error with django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

This question seems to be asked before but none of the answers I came across solve my issue.

I'm getting the following error when I try running the server with `python manage.py runserver`:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'tutorial.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

The error goes away if I change models.py so that my Item class does not extend `models.Model`.

These are the relevant files:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from .models import Item

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')

class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('url', 'name')

class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'owner', 'price')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer, ItemSerializer
from .models import Item

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer

class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows items to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from tutorial.quickstart import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register('groups', views.GroupViewSet)
router.register('items', views.ItemViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Comment: Can you include views as well ? because you import only views in your urls.py ,so the issue wlll  be probably somewhere there.

Comment: Added views.py as well.

Comment: like it is, seems fine to me. What is ROOT_URLCONF set to in your settings file ? and what is your project structure ?